# There is not enough space to download and unpack the index for 'central'

Tags: netbeans-16

[image]

hello,ok on my computer i have 3 partitions

- the "/" linux partition with 60G
- the "home" with 121G
- Swap with 4G
  and when I start to download all the index, I got this message.

I tried to change the address of the `userdir` and `cachedir` of the `netbeans.conf` but it didn't work so I commented it and then I tried to create directories in the 120G partition and I made a symbolic link to have the directory `.cache` and `.netbeans` in this partition which is the one where I have more free space, but every time I get this message.
I was hoping that with any of these I would not get the message and I would download the indexes.

[image]

Comment: You were "hoping"???  Do you know how large the "central" index is?

Comment: not really, but on another computer with ubuntu those folders do not weigh more than 1G

Comment: When you say "with 60G", do you mean 60GB free, or a 60GB partition size?  `df -h` will show you space available.  Do you know which disk `/run` lives on?

Comment: I mean the partition is 60G but I have 30G free, /run is the same partition.

Comment: I see the original is complaining about `/home`.  How much is free there?

Comment: there I have 60G free

Comment: NetBeans bug report [NETBEANS-3582
Not enough space to download and unpack index for Maven 'Central Repository'](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3582) addresses this issue. It was closed with the resolution _"Not A Bug"_. In that case the problem was not due to NetBeans, but related to the space available for the user's **/tmp** directory. If you don't think that explains your problem then provide much more information on the actual error that occurred.